# Maximum total length for commit message with Magit

Tags: magit

I know that it's possible to limit the length of the commit message's first line with `git-commit-summary-max-length`, but is there a way to limit the **total** number of characters in a commit message?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: Granted, this is a very non-standard use, but I'm experimenting with using commit messages on null-tree commits (`--allow-empty`) as a way to take notes / microblog: https://twitter.com/agentofuser/status/1157000550061355010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the hook `git-commit-finish-query-functions` to implement arbitrary restrictions.